# How to query data from strapi by relation using grqphql?

Tags: graphql, strapi

I have two tables in my Strapi, one is `question` and another one is `question_option`.
I have `question_id` in `question_option` table. I want to select all questions with their option. The problem is there that in Strapi we must query from `question_option`, we can't do it from `question`. According to every option, for example, if I have 30 option, it brings question 30 times. So how can I select a question that brings its options?

```
query{
  questionOptions(filters: { question_id:{for : { contains: "owner" }}}){
  data{
     id
     attributes{
      option,
      score,
      status,
      question_id{
        data{
          id
          attributes{
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

**The result is like:**

```
{
"data": {
"questionOptions": {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "44",
      "attributes": {
        "option": " 0-10",
        "score": "1",
        "status": "1",
        "question_id": {
          "data": {
            "id": "5",
            "attributes": {
              "title": "Client Base"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "45",
      "attributes": {
        "option": "11-50",
        "score": "1",
        "status": "1",
        "question_id": {
          "data": {
            "id": "5",
            "attributes": {
              "title": "Client Base"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "46",
      "attributes": {
        "option": "51-100",
        "score": "1",
        "status": "1",
        "question_id": {
          "data": {
            "id": "5",
            "attributes": {
              "title": "Client Base"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "47",
      "attributes": {
        "option": "101-200",
        "score": "1",
        "status": "1",
        "question_id": {
          "data": {
            "id": "5",
            "attributes": {
              "title": "Client Base"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "48",
      "attributes": {
        "option": "over 200",
        "score": "1",
        "status": "1",
        "question_id": {
          "data": {
            "id": "5",
            "attributes": {
              "title": "Client Base"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "49",
      "attributes": {
        "option": "Bohemian    ",
        "score": "1",
        "status": "1",
        "question_id": {
          "data": {
            "id": "6",
            "attributes": {
              "title": "Style Identity"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "50",
      "attributes": {
        "option": "Casual    ",
        "score": "1",
        "status": "1",
        "question_id": {
          "data": {
            "id": "6",
            "attributes": {
              "title": "Style Identity"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "51",
      "attributes": {
        "option": "Clean  ",
        "score": "1",
        "status": "1",
        "question_id": {
          "data": {
            "id": "6",
            "attributes": {
              "title": "Style Identity"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "52",
      "attributes": {
        "option": "Classic  ",
        "score": "1",
        "status": "1",
        "question_id": {
          "data": {
            "id": "6",
            "attributes": {
              "title": "Style Identity"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "53",
      "attributes": {
        "option": "Colorful    ",
        "score": "1",
        "status": "1",
        "question_id": {
          "data": {
            "id": "6",
            "attributes": {
              "title": "Style Identity"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
}
```

As you see, it brought for me the question for every option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to set a relation field between `question` and `question_option` content types. Without knowing the purpose of `question_option` I can't say exactly what type of relation it should be. Looking at the returned values I can only assume it should be `question has many question_options`. You'll have to consider it yourself and set the relation field accordingly. Once it is set and you see a `question_option` or `question_options` relation in your `question` content type, depending on the type of the relation you specified, you can query `questions` with their options.